# Making a component property required in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've a Redux-connected `HelloWorld` component in my application with React and Redux:

```js
interface StateProps {
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
}

interface Props extends StateProps {
  text: string;
}

class HelloWorld extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState): StateProps => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HelloWorld);
```

The Props is combined with a `isLoggedIn` (mapped using `mapStateToProps` from my global `AppState`) and `text`. I would like the `text` Prop to be required when using the component, like this:

```html
<HelloWorld text="MyText" />
```

How should I express that?

Comment: You want prop-types: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Comment: Isn't where really other ways to ensure this? I know prop-types, but using TypeScript I thought I was able to handle this in another way.

Answer (score 3):

Install PropTypes library: `npm install prop-types --save`

Then:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
...
//rest of your code
...
HelloWorld.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

This will make `text` property as a string that is Required for your component.

Comment: Beat me to it ;)

Comment: I wrote 700 pages reference when I was 11y'o, that's why :P

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState): StateProps => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn
  };
};

HelloWorld.propTypes = {
   text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HelloWorld);
```